# Espresso test click withIn EditText CompoundDrawables

Tags: android, user-interface, android-edittext, android-drawable, android-espresso

I am learning UI testing using Espresso. In espresso on click of drawable should show another page. But using custom matcher also didn't click that drawable item. How to approach for this?

Want `edittext` with `drawable` like below:-
[image]

Comment: u mean if i click on the image then open another activity ?

Comment: Yeah but its custom vector image. UI test for that